# How to cancel Observable execution with RxJava once all subscribers gets disposed

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

In my code I am creating an Observable like this -

```
Observable observable = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return longlongTask();
            }
        })
```

And then subscribing to it as -

```
Disposable disposable = observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                          .subscribe(string -> showResult(string)
```

My problem is even after I dispose my subscriber using `disposable.dispose()`, the Observable's long running task keeps on running until it finally completes. I would like to know if there is a way for me to stop this longlongTask once there are no subscribers listening to my Observable. Any methods/standard practices any of you have used to tackle this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: It your longlongTask doesn't respond to thread interruptions, we can't do much for you. You can break up your task and use `Observable.create()` where the `ObservableEmitter.isDisposed()` can be checked regularly.

Comment: Make that longLongTask part of the stream, split it by semi-tasks. Doing that you achieve what you want

Comment: @akarnokd Is there any documentation around what events like onDispose causes thread interruptions to happen in Rx ?